# jQuery ajax callback problem

Tags: jquery

I've been using ajax functions like $.post() using jQuery 1.3.2 and was successfull till today, when I switched to v1.4.2 after downloading jquery UI (jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js)
for using jQuery UI's radio buttons (`$( "#radio" ).buttonset();`), which wasn't working with the my version (it said `.buttonset()`is not defined).
After switching to the new version, it seems the callback in `$.post` is not working. The call is made (i see response in firebug)
Can somebody tell me what is wrong and how to fix it? Please tell me if more information is needed. I haven't added any code as I think it's not a coding error.
Thanks
EDIT
This is my code...

```
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
function get() {
    $.post("php.php",{arg:"post"},
           function (data) {
               alert(data);
           });
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="get()" />
```

and php:

```
<?php
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        die('post');
    } else {
        die('get');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please post your $.post callback code.  The way that callbacks work changed subtely in 1.4.2, especially when performing a replace with html that containes embedded javascript

Comment: yes. I've set datatype to json. I also tried a test script with text return, but no luck..

Comment: @shyam - Can you post the response? Invalid JSON will silently fail in jQuery 1.4+

Comment: @Clicktricity: In a test code of mine, the callback has only an alert; with php returning text. So it's like ...,function(data) { alert(data) });

Comment: Suggest you add an error handler to the $.post and if that is raised the return values should point you in the right direction

Comment: @Nick -  Even text response is not working... I just have a die('asd'); in my php and alert(data) in callback

Comment: @shyam - What's the datatype set to when you're doing that?  If it's JSON then it's *still* invalid JSON.

Comment: I haven't set datatype when it's text response, removed it after JSON failed

Comment: Could this be a problem with the new serialization?  Did you try jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

Comment: @AutoSponge - I havent tried that... could you tell me how?

Comment: @shyam - there is documentation on how 1.4 changed serialization methods: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/ and http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14

Comment: Well, thanks for all you guys suggestions... but somehow the thing got sorted out on itself. I haven't edited anything..I just loaded the page today, and it was working, so I'm assuming that was some browser problem or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

What's the content-type sent in response header from your server? I was able to reproduce it here http://jsfiddle.net/F58Yu/4/ by forcing text/xml as response content-type and invalid XML as content.

Not with any other types though.. With no dataType set that is.

```
function get() {
$.post("/echo/xml/",{xml:"<test>a/test>"},
       function (data) {
           alert(data);              
           console.log("Returned");
           console.dir(data);
       });
```

}​

The address and POST-data is a feature of jsfiddle for testing ajax, does what I described.